# Error googlemaps when try add platform iOS

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

My project run fine on browser, but when I try add platform iOS, I get this error (code below)

Apparently the problem is “cordova-plugin-googlemaps”

I have removed the platform. Then added CocoaPods ($ “sudo gem install cocoapods”), then add:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

but I still getting the error.

What is wrong? Can you help me?

Thanks.

```
--[cordova-plugin-googlemaps]------------------------
From version 2.4.5, the cordova-plugin-googlemaps uses CocoaPod.
No longer necessary com.googlemaps.ios plugin.
Automatic uninstalling com.googlemaps.ios plugin...
-----------------------------------------------------
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-googlemaps': undefined
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!\':\u001b[31m[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.\u001b[39m (CLAide::Help)\n\n\u001b[4mUsage:\u001b[24m\n\n    $ \u001b[32mpod\u001b[39m \u001b[32mCOMMAND\u001b[39m\n\n      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.\n\n\u001b[4mCommands:\u001b[24m\n\n    \u001b[32m+ cache\u001b[39m      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache\n    \u001b[32m+ env\u001b[39m        Display pod environment\n    \u001b[32m+ init\u001b[39m       Generate a Podfile for the current directory\n    \u001b[32m+ install\u001b[39m    Install projectdependencies according to versions from a\n                 Podfile.lock\n    \u001b[32m+ ipc\u001b[39m        Inter-process communication\n    \u001b[32m+ lib\u001b[39m        Develop pods\n    \u001b[32m+ list\u001b[39m       List pods\n    \u001b[32m+ outdated\u001b[39m   Show outdated project dependencies\n    \u001b[32m+ repo\u001b[39m       Manage spec-repositories\n    \u001b[32m+ setup\u001b[39m      Setup the CocoaPods environment\n    \u001b[32m+ spec\u001b[39m       Manage pod specs\n    \u001b[32m+ update\u001b[39m     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock\n\n\u001b[4mOptions:\u001b[24m\n\n    \u001b[34m--silent\u001b[39m     Show nothing\n    \u001b[34m--version\u001b[39m    Show the version of the tool\n    \u001b[34m--verbose\u001b[39m    Show more debugging information\n    \u001b[34m--no-ansi\u001b[39m    Show output without ANSI codes\n    \u001b[34m--help\u001b[39m       Show help banner of specified command\n\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run\'\n\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>\'\n\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load\'\n\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>\'\n'
    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova platform add ios --save exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` not working in newer version of cocoapods. Therefore using an old version of cocoapods, 1.2.1 worked for me.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.2.1
```